# How to check if one value in a 1-D array is at least one, and all others are zero?

Tags: java, arrays

I need my Java program to check if **exactly one** value in my 1-D array is non-zero and all other values **are** zero. Here's what I have so far.

```
public void winningConditions()//whoever has money when nobody else does wins.
{
    for(int i = 0; i < playerCount.length; i ++)
    {
        if(playerCount[i] > 0)
        {
            //potential winner
        }
        else
            System.out.print("");//nothing happens
    }
}
```

Right now this doesn't do anything. I'm stuck. Also, int[] playerCount keeps track of all the players money. The slot number is the player number and the value inside the slot is the amount of money the player has. For example, if playerCount[0] = 3 then player zero has $3.00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public boolean winningConditions()  {
    int noPlayersWithMoney = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < playerCount.length; i ++)
    {
        if(playerCount[i] > 0)
        {
            noPlayersWithMoney++;
        }
    }
    if (noPlayersWithMoney == 1)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Now how do I print a statement saying "Player ___ wins!" ?

Comment: Travis:  Considering this request, I would rewrite the above code to return the player number that wins, returning a -1 if no one wins.  Let me know if you want me to post the code for this...

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean winningConditions()//whoever has money when nobody else does wins.
{
    int noPlayersWithMoney = 0;
    int winner = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < playerCount.length; i ++)
    {
        if(playerCount[i] > 0)
        {
            noPlayersWithMoney++;
            winner = playerCount[i];
        }
    }
    if(noPlayersWithMoney == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("Player "+winner+" has won the game!");
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

I think this works.